# Cucumber Java Fail Fast

Tags: java, cucumber

We are using Java based Cucumber project.

Would like to know if there is fail fast option.
If I am running 10 scenarios & if 2nd test fails my tests should stop after 2nd scenario.

```
static boolean prevScenarioFailed = false;
  @Before
    public void teardown(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        prevScenarioFailed = scenario.isFailed();
        if(env.getProperty("fail_fast").toString().equalsIgnoreCase( "true")) {
            if (prevScenarioFailed) {

                throw new RuntimeException("Fail!");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip all cucumber-jvm scenarios when first scenario is failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49260902/how-to-skip-all-cucumber-jvm-scenarios-when-first-scenario-is-failed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming the runner is in **junit**.

**Case 1 - Skip all scenarios after a specific scenario fails.**

Use a specific tag like (`@SkipCheck`) on the scenario on which you want to fail fast on failure in the feature file.

Add the following in the `stepdefinition or hook class`.

```
    private static boolean skipFlag = false;

    @Before
    public void beforeSkipCount() {
        if(skipFlag)
            Assume.assumeTrue(false);
    }

    @After
    public void afterSkipCount(Scenario scen) {
        if(scen.getSourceTagNames().contains("@SkipCheck") && scen.isFailed())
            skipFlag = true;
    }
```

**Case 2 - Skip all scenarios after a specific count of scenario fails.**

```
private static int skipCount = 0;
private static final int ALLOWED_FAIL_TEST_COUNT = 2;

@Before
public void beforeSkipCount() {
    if(skipCount == ALLOWED_FAIL_TEST_COUNT)
        Assume.assumeTrue(false);
}

@After
public void afterSkipCount(Scenario scen) {
    if(scen.isFailed())
        skipCount++;
}
```

If you have multiple runners in the project and want to skip scenarios in them too then you need to copy the contents of the `Before` hook to the junit `BeforeClass` hook. Change the access of the flags accordingly.